# Cannot load project by opening .csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Sorry, i am new to VS... :'(

I am currently using VS2010. When i am trying to double-click a .csproj to load a project, it just load a XML instaed of all the associated .cs / properties / reference files. I did previously can load other projects with .csproj. So i am wondering if it's related to the project itself.

Any way I can spot/check the reason/root-cause of it? (from the XML file loaded?)
Is it because the project is previously developed using other older VS, like VS2008 / VS2005?

Thanks.

Comment: Try right-click, "open with", and select Visual Studio.

Comment: or, open VS and there choose "open project".

Comment: Yes. I used VS to open it. The XML is then shown in VS2010

Comment: Do you have C# project support installed?

Comment: it's ok now. I just load other projects' class and then, reload the .csproj in the question.

Comment: Aren't you trying to open a .csproj.user instead? the .user usually is not shown by windows.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you have accidentally changed the default file association of your .csproj files.  Go into the Control Panel -> Default Programs -> Set Associations to see what application is set to open the file and change it to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
2. Click Folder Options.
3. Click File Types tab in Folder Options window and the full file
   types and their association will be listed.
4. Click New and type the File Extension in the box and then click
   Advanced.
5. Choose an association for the file type.
6. Click OK and then Click Close.
7. Open the file again